# Implenting log-gamma using recursion

Tags: r, recursion, gamma

I am trying to calculate `lgamma` using recursion. But it does not work as expected and gives out `Nan` and `-Inf`. What could be the reason for this?

```
sum = 0
log_gamma_recursive <- function(n) {
  if(n == 1){
    return(1)
  }else{
    sum = sum + log(log_gamma_recursive(n-1))
    print(sum)
    return(sum)
  }
}#log 4  + log 3 + log 2 + log 1
log_gamma_recursive(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things wrong with the code:

1. `sum` should not be a global variable, because successive "external" calls will return an accumulated value
2. You add the `log` of the return value to `sum`. This will give a series of *nested* logs:

   - You get `log 4 + log(log 3 + log(log 2 + log (log 1))))`, which is obviously wrong
   - `log(log 1) = log 0` which tends to negative infinity mathematically speaking, but the library may or may not categorize this as a valid input
3. `log_gamma(1)` is 0, not 1

With that in mind, try this:

```
log_gamma_recursive <- function(n) {
  if (n <= 1) {
    return (0)
  }else{
    sum = (log(n-1) + log_gamma_recursive(n-1))
    print(sum)
    return(sum)
  }
}
```

Comment: Successive calls won't accumulate since the assignment of new values is within the scope of the function

Comment: @aocall yeah I probably should have phrased that better; I meant that if he made more than one "*external*" call to `log_gamma_recursive`, the value of `sum` would be the sum of the returns from the latest and all previous "external" calls

Comment: What do you mean by "external"? In fact, since the assigned value of `sum` doesn't contain a reference to the previous `sum` value, it doesn't matter if any value is assigned

Comment: @aocall `sum` is defined outside the function, so if he were to do multiple explicit calls e.g. `log_gamma_recursive(5)`, the value would be accumulated. Please test this for yourself instead of arguing over how to better express this idea

Comment: I did, and it doesn't make any difference. I don't know why you think it would. I was trying to understand if "external" meant something different to what I thought it meant.

Comment: `sum <- 0; stupid_fun <- function(x) sum <- sum + x; stupid_fun(1); stupid_fun(10); sum`

Answer (score 1):

Since R can carry out vectorized computations, It is safe to perform log on the resulting vector and sum.

```
 ll=function(x)sum(log(1:(x-1)))
```

what is the benefit of this? This can compute values which the `log_gamma_recursive` cannot compute. Recall `log_gamma_recursive` is a nested function and thus fails at some point depending on the machine capacity. eg:

```
log_gamma_recursive(3476)
[1] 24862.89
ll(3476)
[1] 24862.89
```

In this machine, `log_gamma_recursive` does not work for any number greater than 3476:

```
log_gamma_recursive(3477)
Error: C stack usage  7970456 is too close to the limit
```

while on the other hand, the `ll` function works:

```
ll(3477)
[1] 24871.04
```

At the same time, the `ll` function is far much faster than the `log_recursive` function:

```
system.time(for(i in 1:10000)ll(3000))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.313   0.036   0.350 
system.time(for(i in 1:10000)log_gamma_recursive(3000))
   user  system elapsed 
 20.569   0.100  20.794
```

Those units are in seconds!!